# g++ segmentation fault when enabling optimization

Tags: c++, optimization, segmentation-fault

Why this code generates segmentation fault, when I enable optimization (flag -O2/-03).
When add assert before return, then all OK.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <vector>
#include <assert.h>


struct doublet {

    doublet(double val1 = 0, double val2 = 0) {
        dob[0] = val1;
        dob[1] = val2;
    }

    template< class Expr >
    doublet& operator=(Expr const& x){
        dob[0] = x[0];
        dob[1] = x[1];
        return *this;
    }

    const double&  operator[](unsigned ix) const  {
      /*
       * BUG HERE
       */
      //assert(ix<2);
      return dob[ix];
    }


    void print(){
        std::cout << (*this)[0] << std::endl;
        std::cout << (*this)[1] << std::endl;
    }
private:
      double dob[2];
};

struct plus {

    static double  apply( double a,  double b)  {
        return a + b;
    }
};

struct minus {

      static double  apply(double a, double b){
        return a - b;
    }
};



template <class L, class OpTag, class R>
struct Expression {

    Expression (L const& l, R const& r) :l(l),r(r){}

    L const& l;
    R const& r;

    typedef const double result_type;

    result_type operator[](unsigned ix) const {
        return  OpTag::apply(l[ix],r[ix]);
    }

};

template <class L, class R>
Expression<L,plus,R> operator+(L const& l, R const& r){
    return Expression<L,plus,R>(l,r);
}

template <class L, class R>
Expression<L,minus,R> operator-(L const& l, R const& r){
    return Expression<L,minus,R>(l,r);
}

int main()
{
    doublet a(4.0,1.0), b(5.1,3.3), c(7.4,5.2);

    Expression<Expression<doublet, plus, doublet>, plus, doublet> 
    k = b + a + c;
    std::cout << k[0] << " " << k[1] << std::endl;

}
```

[Assembler instructions](http://pastebin.com/SFL0cT8N) to this code. Segmentation fault reached on 20 line (edx=0).

**UPDATE**. I'll figure out what's problem. For stable working need declare k as **doublet** or add to Expression class **operator=**. Case with **L const&** is not right, because it create template objects ([Herb Sutter](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/) about const reference to rvalue).

Comment: which compiler? g++ 4.8.1 compiles this fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
Expression (L const& l, R const& r) :l(l),r(r){}

L const& l;
```

You are binding `l` by reference. Then in your usage:

```
Expression<Expression<doublet, plus, doublet>, plus, doublet> 
    k = b + a + c;
```

`b + a` creates a temporary, but it exists only until end of statement. In next line `k.l` is a dangling reference.

Comment: Yep - I would welcome passing a references to const where that reference is no temporaray !

Comment: Yes, it work. Then in my case it's must not worked. Why my case works with assert?

Comment: @crastinus: undefined behavior

Comment: @crastinus welcome to the world of undefined behavior. Sometimes things might appear to work (here probably because space used by temporary is not reused) even if program is invalid. Then small, seemingly unimportant change in code or compiler flags can make it fail again.